# How to fix data no loading in hard refresh/ cache clean refresh

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to display a particular div inside a section depending on the value of my flag. I am not able to display it as soon as I clear the cache and try to load it. This is happening for the first time only i.e. after I clear the cache and load response for the first time. Rest of the time its working fine.

```
tried using v-if and v-else-if, in where I had two seactions, But that gave other issues like some of my tables and columns did not load.

// .js file

processResponse: function(response){
            if(!response.data){
                return false;
            }

            if(response.data.error !== undefined){

                this.animateResults();

            } else {

                this.flag = response.data.flag

                if(this.flag){
                    $("div.scheme-lookup-component-descoped").show();
                    $("div.scheme-lookup-component-results-notdescoped").hide();
                }
                 else{
                    $("div.scheme-lookup-component-results-notdescoped").show();
                    $("div.scheme-lookup-component-descoped").hide();
                    //this.animateResults();
                }
            }

            animateResults: function() {
            const self = this;
            if(!this.resultsShown) {
                Vue.nextTick(function() {
                    $(".scheme-lookup-component-results").velocity("slideDown", {
                        duration: 500,
                        complete: function () {
                            $('.scheme-lookup-component-results__title-section').velocity('scroll', {duration:1000, easing: "ease-in-out", offset: -16});
                            customPrint.preparePageForPrint();
                            self.resultsShown = true;
                        }
                    },);
                })

# html code #

<section class="scheme-lookup-component-results" style="display: none">
    <div class="scheme-lookup-component-descoped" style="display: none" v-html="resultsContentData.deScopedEppMessage"></div>
       <div class = "scheme-lookup-component-results-notdescoped">
       </div>
</section>
```

Expected result is that I should be able to view my div even after clearing the cache and loading it. As of now, I am unable to view the  result after I clean up the cache

Comment: Sounds like an issue with how `processResponse()` is called or handled. How do you call it and what value does response have when the data does Not load?

Comment: process response has the json object which in displayed in the screen. The processResponse() loads but there is a problem withthe show and hide I guess. As a result the class is not loading.

Comment: How and when do you generate the request that `processResponse()` handles? Since you mention caching as the root cause, there's probably something wrong with when or how the request is called, or how the response is handled. Since `processResponse()` does not show anything changing the response, I don't think the issue is with the code shown. Else clearing / not clearing the cache should not change anything.

Comment: i have a submit button , which on click calls the process response and it fetches the response:

Comment: `performSchemeRequest: function(schemeId){

   this.isLoading = true;
   axios.get(url, {
    withCredentials: true
   })
    .then(function(response){
     self.processResponse(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
     self.isLoading = false;
     console.log(error);
    });
  },`

Comment: Hey @Shilly , anything on the above issue? I am having a hard time here solving that

Comment: Not really. I don't understand the problem correctly. If the request only gets fired when the submit button is pushed, I do not understand how the caching is involved. Are you using a input type submit, reloading the entire page and then wondering why the result of the submit is no longer visible? Is there a difference between the cached version and the direct from server version of the response, which should not happen?